# How to merge bounding boxes in a image with OpenCV

Tags: google-colaboratory

[My output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsuzx.png)
[Raw Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ddx7.jpg)

I want to merge the last two bounding boxes using easyocr, height_ths (float, default = 0.5) - Maximum different in box height.
But, I am not able to merge the bounding boxes. Please help me to get out of this.
thanks inadvance.

This is my code, I got only bounding boxes.

```
image = "/content/drive/MyDrive/DLD_Project/Passport_Data/100_Images_content/100_Images/1.jpg"
image = PIL.Image.open(image)
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
bounds = reader.readtext('/content/drive/MyDrive/DLD_Project/Passport_Data/100_Images_content/100_Images/1.jpg')

from PIL import ImageDraw

def draw_boxes(image, bounds, color='yellow', width=2, box_size=3):
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    for bound in bounds:
        p0, p1, p2, p3 = bound[0]
        # Increase size of bounding box by box_size pixels in all directions
        p0 = (p0[0]-box_size, p0[1]-box_size)
        p1 = (p1[0]+box_size, p1[1]-box_size)
        p2 = (p2[0]+box_size, p2[1]+box_size)
        p3 = (p3[0]-box_size, p3[1]+box_size)
        draw.line([*p0, *p1, *p2, *p3, *p0], fill=color, width=width)
    return image

draw_boxes(image, bounds)
```

I want to merge bounding boxes vertically and I want to crop the image from the passport image to feed it to mrz codechecker to extract mrz text